# Bloquear Orientación de pantalla en ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda, estoy buscando información en varios lugares pero no encuentro solución al respecto. Estoy haciendo una aplicación con ionic 3 pero por una disposición de los elementos necesito que la orientación del dispositivo sea siempre horizontal. Hay forma de bloquearlo horizontalmente?. Muchas gracias por todo.

Comment: tal vez con este plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas el plugin Cordova Screen Orientation e Ionic Native.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
npm install --save @ionic-native/screen-orientation
```

Y lo usarías así:

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation';

constructor(private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation) { }

...


// get current
console.log(this.screenOrientation.type); // logs the current orientation, example: 'landscape'

// set to landscape
this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE);
// Act on orientation change.
this.screenOrientation.onChange().subscribe(
   () => {
       console.log("Orientation Changed");
   }
);
```

Tienes los detalles en el plugin de Cordova [Screen Orientation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation/).

Comment: Hola disculpa mi ignorancia pero ese codigo donde lo debo colocar? en cada module.ts de cada pagina que hago?

Comment: Una forma sería  tener una clase de la que hereden todas tus páginas donde pongas el ćodigo relacionado con la orientación, así solo lo "pones" una vez. Supongo que también puedes usar el plugin en un código que se ejecute al inicio de la app, suscribirte al evento de cambio de orientación y tratar de actuar desde ahí, pero hace meses que no uso Ionic y ahora mismo no recuerdo si esa aproximación valdrá.

Comment: Bueno, estare viendo como hacerlo porque en la documentación no dice como :c y lo intente poner en cada pagina pero no me funciono

Answer (score -1):

En config.xml , tienes que añadir si lo quieres horizontal:

```
< preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

Y si lo quieres vertical:

```
< preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```